# how to sign PHP sourcecode

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature, code-signing, phar

I want to distribute some PHP sourcecode, 
I need to provide a way to verify that these sourcecode aren't altered.

So basically I want to sign them (if possible using PHP) and later to check their signature (using PHP is mandatory, it have to work both on linux and windows).

I've been digging around, and what I found is that :

- signing :

  - you can create a zip archive using [PharData](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.phardata.php)
  - you can create pub/priv using [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php).
  - you can sign a PharData using [Phar::setSignatureAlgorithm](http://php.net/manual/fr/phardata.setsignaturealgorithm.php)
  - you seems to have to put the public key alongside the archive ([source](http://www.robpeck.com/2015/07/securely-signing-php-phar-files-with-openssl) (read step 3)) : 
    *The public key must be named the same name as the Phar file, with .pubkey added, and must be in the same directory as your Phar.*
- verifying :

  - I didn't found anything, I guess that [PharData::extractTo](http://php.net/manual/fr/phardata.extractto.php) is sufficient

**if anyone can validate this process (or indicate a better one), it would be a great help.**

Because I tried to give what theoretical solution I found from now, but between theory and practice, their should be a gap. Especially considering that I'm new to this concept, and that it is of the uttermost importance for my project to be solid on the security aspect.
I remind that using apple's signing process was a pain in the ass several years ago and I'm not confident in my ability to create secured solution.

Comment: what i get from the article you linked: if your signed PHAR doesn't check out or the pubkey is missing, it just won't execute - so there is nothing to do for you. besides that: what exactly **is your question**? just "if anyone has feedback" on an idea is too broad.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann : my question is "how to sign PHP sourcecode". I proposed what seem to be a theoretical solution, but I am no expert and it may be a bad one. So the question remain "how to", on possible answer beeing "as you proposed". I edit my question that way. Thanks

Comment: "if anyone can validate this process (or indicate a better one), it would be a great help." - have you tried it? Should take an hour or so, and then you'll know it works for your circumstances. FWIW - yes, the process is correct, but there are two clarifications: firstly, the runtime interpreter verifies the key. You don't have to do that. Secondly, I've found performance problems for large web applications using signed PHARs.

Comment: Note that *anybody* can create a key pair and sign source code. You need to *trust* the public key to verify the signature. The way it is written by the article is that the public key can be saved so that *subsequent* updates are verified to come from the same sender. For the initial package to be trusted you either need to use a certificate where the chain can be trusted (PKI) or you need to validate the public key using a separate channel (e.g. verifiying a hash over the public key over the phone, things like that).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : you're right. I've searched a little in order to find out how the process would be, but I didn't found anything. I imagine that the public key would have to be submitted to a Certificate Authority whou would verify some key point, and then... I don't know, what material they give and how to integrate them into the process, because from what i guess, the public key would not be changed...

Comment: A CA usually embeds the public key into a leaf certificate that has been trusted for code signing. If they are going to trust you and if you are going to hand the over money. But then the CAis going to need to be trusted as well and the client cannot just validate the certificate against e.g. a DNS as performed for TLS. Aint key management *fun*?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding signed phar files, the last time I checked, the default behaviour was:

- if signature is valid, retrieve file from phar (and execute if php)
- if signature is invalid, throw an error
- if no signature, retrieve file from phar (and execute if php)

Hence it is simple to bypass the protection of signing by simply stripping out the signature (actually, you just need to flag the file as not signed). You can explicitly set the [phar.require_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.require-hash) option which removes this backdoor in the instance.

> to verify that these sourcecode aren't altered

hmmmm. this is a bit vague. Modified by whom? As above you need the client to opt-in to a security model based on phar signing.

There are a lot of third party PHP encoders which work by obfuscating the code. Almost all of them provide a laughable level of protection. A couple of exceptions are IonCube encoder and Zend's encoder. I'm not sufficiently familiar with these to say how strong they are and whether they meet your requirement.

There were a couple of open source PHP compilers which would convert PHP source code to a .so extension (notably Facebook HipHop) but I don't think either are being maintained.

If you merely want to ensure that validated content is available to your customers (and you're not concerned about your customers modifying the files) then just use standard file signing with PGP or x509.

If you want to prevent your customers from modifying the PHP code, then the only option I am aware of (and haven't tested it myself) is to distribute your code as HHVM bytecode - but this is not resistant to reverse engineering, has no intrinsic, secure verification mechanism and is really not intended as a method of protecting the code.

Comment: Thank you, since I just want to ensure that the files customers uses are from me.
I used a json file embeded within the archive containing the files, it rely on `openssl_sign` to sign the sourcecode. This file contians the signature and some payload (ie the pubkey)

Comment: First let us use the right terms. OP is looking for a non-repudiation code signing. He want’s to prove the origin of the content and that the content wasn’t changed in transit, so your answer regarding the obfuscation is completely off topic. Code signing is done using private key corresponding to the certificate issued for its public key. Such certificate must be signed by the CA trusted by the customer. What customer does on their side is their problem really and you shouldn’t trust them. You sign code to make sure that you are not liable if someone runs altered version of it.

Comment: No - the OP asked for the code to be tamper proof - that's not the same thing as non-repudiation but there is a lot of overlap. Non-repudiation is a mechanism for proving the provenance of some data - thats not the same thing as making decisions about what to do if that provenance defaults. Both ioncube and Zend's encoders claim to address the issue of provenance and provide a menchaism for enforcing a polic based that.

Comment: He says "I need to provide a way to verify that this sourcecode aren't altered." the content origination is implicit in this case as you can't prove that something was not changed without signing initial version of it. This causes a lot of confusion as there are different flags on certificate that can technically solve the problem, but main difference is their legal interpretation. Code signing, digital signature. and nonrepudiation do the same thing under the hood, but only one of them is legally binding.